# Serverless Event object failed validation at createError

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb, middleware, serverless

I am working on a serverless/nodejs12 project.  The project deploys fine, but when I try to invoke the endpoint with postman I get the following error.  I have browsed through many postings of similar errors but still failed to understand what's going on.  Will appreciate any pointers.

Thank you

```
    at createError (/var/task/src/handlers/webpack:/home/serverless-workspace/notification/node_modules/@middy/util/index.js:259:1)
    at validatorMiddlewareBefore (/var/task/src/handlers/webpack:/home/serverless-workspace/notification/node_modules/@middy/validator/index.js:55:1)
    at runMiddlewares (/var/task/src/handlers/webpack:/home/serverless-workspace/notification/node_modules/@middy/core/index.js:120:1)
    at runRequest (/var/task/src/handlers/webpack:/home/serverless-workspace/notification/node_modules/@middy/core/index.js:80:1) {
  details: [
    {
      instancePath: '/body',
      schemaPath: '#/properties/body/type',
      keyword: 'type',
      params: [Object],
      message: 'must be object'
    }
  ]

createNotification.js
--------------------------
async function createNotification(event, context) {
    const { title } = event.body;
    const { destination } = event.body;
    const { destinationType } = event.body

    const notification = {
        id: uuid(),
        title,
        destination,
        destinationType,
        status: 'OPEN',
        createdAt: new Date().toISOString(),
    }

    try {
        await dynamodb.put({
            TableName: process.env.NOTIFY_TABLE_NAME,
            Item: notification
        }).promise();
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        throw new createError.InternalServerError(error);
    }
    return {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify(notification),
    };
}

export const handler = commonMiddleware(createNotification)
    .use(validator({ inputSchema: createNotificationSchema }));

and the schema
----------------------
const schema = {
    type: 'object',
    properties: {
        body: {
            type: 'object',
            required: ['status'],
            default: { status: 'OPEN' },
            properties: {
                status: {
                    default: 'OPEN',
                    enum: ['OPEN', 'CLOSED'],
                },
            },
        },
    },
    required: ['body'],
};

export default schema;
```

Answer (score 1):

You're getting the error `must be object`. I'm guessing your input looks like `{ event: { body: 'JSON string' } }`. You'll need to use another middy middleware to parse the body prior to validating the input. Which middleware will depend on what AWS event it's expecting. Middy >3.0.0 supports all AWS events.